# Conversion of .bat file to open and load putty session into Python

Tags: python, subprocess, putty

I have a `.bat` file which takes some arguments and connect to putty using python. Below is code for reference.

```
pushd c:
start /min Putty.exe -load SessionName -l UserName -pw Password
```

I am calling `putty1.bat` file in python using `os.system` as mentioned below:

```
os.system('putty1.bat')
```

I have seen some reference related to `subprocess` but it's not helping me out how to pass above mentioned parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need access to input and output streams, the `os.spawn...` function family should provide what you want.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher could you please provide any example if possible.

Comment: ignore my previous deleted answer there is dependency of path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Plink` which is a command line application. [here more info](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter7.html)

```
import subprocess

sp = subprocess.Popen(['plink', '-ssh', '-l', 'username', '-pw', 'password', 'SessionName'], \
                     shell = False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
sp.communicate('lmstat -a\nexit\n'.encode())
```

OR try with [paramiko](https://qxf2.com/blog/ssh-using-python-paramiko/)

```
import paramiko
import socket


class Point:
    def __init__(self,host,username,password,port):
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.port = port

    def connect(self):
        """Login to the remote server"""

        print("Establishing ssh connection")
        self.client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        # Connect to the server
        self.client.connect(hostname=self.host, port=self.port, username=self.username, password=self.password,
                                timeout=1000, allow_agent=False, look_for_keys=False)
        print("Connected to the server", self.host)
```

Comment: Thanks @Govind Parashar for reply, 'sp.stdin.write("echo y")' not working. Please suggest

Comment: try with sp.communicate('lmstat -a\nexit\n'.encode())

Comment: Now getting warning `The new rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 1e:b3:00:d8:2b:30:69:0d:fd:01:a9:f1:53:c7:06:d6
If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.`

Comment: any other suggestion?

Comment: @JitendraBanshpal : you can use Paramiko : [Paramiko](https://qxf2.com/blog/ssh-using-python-paramiko/)

Comment: Thanks @govindparashar it's working as expected without error. could you please share code you have tried, I might need to re verify.